# Signing a Pre-Packaged APK for the Android Market

Tags: android, apk, google-play, sign, pre-packaged

Firstly I am not a Developer - I am just creating a simple application. In fact I am not really creating, rather modifying an existing application.
The application in question was made for a UK market, and I needed an AU market (this is in terms of the Images used) and thus it was quite simple to open the APK which I downloaded and edit the Images as required. I then signed it using the AutoSign App, and added it to my phone, where it runs as good as the original.
I submitted it to the original developer - who asked if he could post it on the Market. I was happy for him to do this. However, as I used the Auto Sign tool, the following error was reported: Market does not accept apks signed with certificates issued by Android team. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
Now like I said I am not a developer, and whilst I have the Android and Java SDK and Eclipse installed, and Android App Maker installed, I am still unable to do what I wan't to do - that is create a valid sign key and sign my packaged APK (even if I have to un package it via Compressed folder) with this for distribution to the Market.
Any assistance you can offer is much appreciated!
Sincere regards,
Ryan Carmichael

Answer (score 1):

Why not send an unsigned version to him and let him sign it with his developer license? He obviously has a valid one if he's already got apps in the market.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say that - he had someone else do all that for him - hence why it falls on myself to figure it out now...

Comment: Try taking a look at this page. It has a bunch of information you might find useful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link - however I have already read through that, and tried to do it - but to no avail. I am having trouble using the SDK as they say. Is there no simpler way to do this?

Comment: I tried this: 
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/
But couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out myself - 
To create a key:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore keystore.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

To test the key:
keytool -keystore keystore.keystore -list -v

To apply the key:
jarsigner -verbose -keystore keystore.keystore -signedjar apk_signed.apk apk.apk alias_name

Hope this helps someone!
Ryan